# Under what circumstances do questions and answers allow me to comment?

Tags: comments, support

I'm looking at several questions. Sometimes I can comment because there is a clear mechanism to do so, a big edit field similar to the one offered for an answer.

Other times, even on very recent issues, I cannot find how to submit a comment. The topic doesn't look closed in any way I can see and, in some cases, hasn't even been answered yet.

I guess I'm blind, the interface is very busy, whatever the reason, but how do I add a comment when I don't have an answer and don't want to answer, but wish to contribute to what may become an answer?

Comment: And, yeah, there was an opportunity to add a comment to this post and I took it. Why can't I always see such an opportunity in forum posts?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a forum - is a Question and Answer system.

Answer (score 6):

You can always comment on your own questions and answer to your questions.

You need 50 reputation points to comment on other peoples' posts.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: There are also *rare* occasions when a moderator will Lock a post. In that case, comments and new answers cannot be added.